# how to do get the result if we have str and int both in one line

Tags: python

I have two line and both have str and int and want to subtract and want to get result.

e.g

```
Total databases are         300
Total completed database    200
```

result should be come `100`

Comment: Try it yourself first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
your_string =  '''
                Total databases are         300
                Total completed database    200
                '''

numbers = [int(s) for s in your_string.split() if s.isdigit()]

print numbers[0]-numbers[1]

>>>100
```

Comment: how can I get two or multiple integer value from a single line. e.g total completed database 200 out of 300. result should be like 200 and 300

Answer (score 0):

split by " ", get the last element of the row, subtract last elements.

Comment: You can't subtract strings... (There's another step)

Comment: But you Can parse them to int example: int('10') will give you 10

Comment: Certainly, but you didn't mention that step.

Comment: I was thinking too fast